# vscode webview - passing huge json data from webview to external js

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, webview, security-policy

I code vscode extension and I use webview for presenting text.
The text is stored in json file - this is huge file, and there is a lot of text.
Some words from that text need present popup window when mouse hover them on the webview.
The words and popup information are stored in json. For example:

```
{
    wordA:{
        popupText: "text"
        //... and other properties
    },
    wordA:{
        popupText: "another text"
        //... and other properties
    }
    // .... and many many other data
}
```

I want to pass this json data from the webview to external js to be able to manage it. Due to security policy I cant just load json from javascript file - and I don't want to break the security policy.

HTML code for proper presenting the data is generated by other functions.

Files conneted to the problem:

- ActivationFile - which push activation method and pass reference of webview.ts to vscode.
- webview.ts file - which have all functionalities which are needed to proper display the content and text information which i want to present
- myScript.js file - loaded to the webview.ts

I want pass data from webview.ts to myScript.js

```
///WebView.ts file
private _getHtmlForWebview(webview: vscode.Webview) {
    const scriptPathOnDisk = vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, 'myScript.js');
    const scriptUri = (scriptPathOnDisk).with({ 'scheme': 'vscode-resource' });
    const jsonPath = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'jsonFile.json'), 'utf8');
    const data = JSON.parse(jsonPath);
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <some html stuff>...
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; style-src ${webview.cspSource}; img-src ${webview.cspSource} https:; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">
        </head>
        <body>
            <some html stuff which is generated automatically by other functions of the program>
            <for presenting text from json, put them into divs, spans and give them proper ids>
            <which will let the javascript manage those divs and spans>...
            <script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptUri}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </body>
        </html>`;
}
```

**nonce** is generated by function in the webview.ts

I tried by adding script tag before myScript is loaded into html

```
<script nonce="${nonce}" type="text/javascript">
    const jsonData = ${data};
</script>
<script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptUri}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but data is not reachable in myScript.

`console.log(jsonData.wordA.popupText)` show error, that jsonData doesn't exists in the scope

`console.log(window.jsonData.wordA.popupText)` shows undefined

I saw some solutions for React, Angular, Vue etc. but this is simple webview and I don't need any big framework here and from what i understand they will not work here.

I also saw something like `acquireVsCodeApi()` but I miss something and I don't have idea how set it in my case.

Comment: Try sending json as [message](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#passing-messages-from-an-extension-to-a-webview) after webview loaded.

Comment: @User863 With this method I can send data from acivationFile.ts to the webview.ts, and I need to send this data from the webview.ts to external javascript myScript.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my specific situation.
The point is about understand what i actually did by separating my files.
ActivationFile has registered method for extension and passed reference to the function which is in the webview.ts file.
In documentation there is no passing - all is done in one file - so in fact my name for 'webview.ts' is misleading because its still the extension, not the webview.

in my webview.ts file I post message (in the same function where webview is created)
`currentPanel.webview.postMessage({command:"dajaJsonCommand", data:dataJson});`

In myScript.js I wrapped everything in DOMContentLoaded event and then follow documentation and set event listener for message from extension.:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (function () {

let dataVariable;
window.addEventListener('message', event => {
    const message = event.data; // The JSON data our extension sent
    switch (message.command) {
        case 'dajaJsonCommand':
            dataVariable = message.data;
            break;
    }
});
```

And then json has been passed to the external script and could be reached by the program. End of the story. I hope its clear, if someone will need more details - let me know.